# Hiding the class(es) just tested with the If statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, hide

Help, I'm trying to hide the class(es) just tested with the if statement. 
Just cant figure out how to make it work. This is the code i've got so far. It does find/get the classes I like(tested with simple alert message).

```
if($('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').attr('class').indexOf('sporttherapie') != -1) {
//make all the div's with a class true to above statment hide (.hide())
}
```

Does somebody knows how to get it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `sporttherapie` isn't an exact class name, you can use the `filter` method ([**DOCS**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)) to reduce the element set and just `hide` those:

```
$('div[class^="cn-list-row"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('class').indexOf('sporttherapie') >= 0;
}).hide();
```

Comment: or use `.filter("[class*='sporttherapie']")`

Comment: Great, That works! 'sporttherapie' indeed isn't the exact class name but part of the class name. ty!

Answer (score 1):

`$("div[class^='cn-list-row').filter(".sporttherapie").hide()`